# using fscanf to parse file

Tags: c++, c, parsing, scanf

I am parsing a file which contains pattern like this

> [0][NAME][DESCRIPTION]

I am using 
`fscanf(fp, "[%d][%s][%s]", &no, &name, &desc)`

and getting these values no=0 and name=NAME][DESCRIPTION] and desc = junk. I tried adding space between the [0] and [Name] which results into no = 0 and name=NAME] what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace both `%s` with `%[^]\n]`.  The `%s` is consuming the `]` and you need to limit the `name` to allowable characters.

Here `]` and `\n` are not allowed to be put in `name`.   You may want `%[A-Za-z_ ]` to limit `name` to letters, _ and space.

---

Related improvements:
A length specifier to avoid overruns.
Consider `fgets()` paired with `sscanf()` vs `fscanf()`.

Comment: That's a nonstandard syntax for scanf isn't it?

Comment: It is mentioned on cplusplus.com and linux.die.net, but not on wikipedia, msdn.

Comment: It is unusual but c11 says "If the conversion specifier begins with [] or [^], the right bracket character is in the scanlist and the next following right bracket character is the matching right bracket that ends the specification;", and it compiles OK and works as expected.

Comment: The `[` or scanset conversion was introduced with C89.

Comment: I don't normally vote on "competition", but in this case your answer is far better than mine.  +1.

Comment: May be nice to mention that `%[`, just like `%s`, is dangerous without a length specifier.

Comment: %[A-za-z_ ] and %[^]\n] include the '[' in the name which is not required

Comment: @Ibrar Ahmed - See edit correction  `%[A-za-z_ ]` s/b `%[A-Za-z_ ]`.  Recommend that you clearly define what `char` should be included in the "name" & "description".  From the post, the only `char` certainly _not_ allowed is the `]`.

Comment: @chux `%[A-Za-z_ ]` does not work at all and name field returns junk, means it unable to  parse. And %[^]\n] return [NAME, in that case '[' does not require. I don't know why I am getting this. By the way I am  running solaris 10 and using Solaris Studio.

Comment: I think were are mis-communicating the entire format.  Use `"[%d][%[A-Za-z_ ]][%[A-Za-z_ ]]"` or `"[%d][%[^]\n]][%[^]\n]]"`.

Answer (score 0):

`%s` reads until it finds a whitespace character, `scanf` is not going to meet your needs here.  You need something else.  Luckily, C++ makes this easy.

I have these functions I use which stream in string or character literals, just stick them in a header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

template<class e, class t, int N>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, const e(&sliteral)[N]) {
        std::array<e, N-1> buffer; //get buffer
        in >> buffer[0]; //skips whitespace
        if (N>2)
                in.read(&buffer[1], N-2); //read the rest
        if (strncmp(&buffer[0], sliteral, N-1)) //if it failed
                in.setstate(std::ios::failbit); //set the state
        return in;
}
template<class e, class t>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, const e& cliteral) {
        e buffer;  //get buffer
        in >> buffer; //read data
        if (buffer != cliteral) //if it failed
                in.setstate(std::ios::failbit); //set the state
        return in;
}
//redirect mutable char arrays to their normal function
template<class e, class t, int N>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, e(&carray)[N]) {
        return std::operator>>(in, carray);
}
```

With these in addition to the standard library, scanning is a little wierd, but simple:

```
int id;
std::string name;
std::string description;

std::cin >> "[" >> id >> "][";
std::getline(std::cin, name, ']'); //read until ]
std::cin >> "][";
std::getline(std::cin, description, ']');  //read until ]
std::cin >> "]";

if (std::cin) {
    //success!  All data was properly read in!
}
```